# Reset Visual Studio default settings while retaining changes made by Resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

I have a machine on which I had to use VS2010 for a project. I installed the project's VS settings (color scheme, formatting etc.) so that I'd be using the same environment as the other developers on the project.

I subsequently installed VS2012 for my own use - it picked up the settings (color, formatting) from the VS2010 install.

I then installed ReSharper into both.

I now want to remove the project's settings from my VS2012, while leaving them in the VS2010 install - I am still working on their project.

I was going to reset VS2012 to its default settings but I don't want to lose the changes that ReSharper makes.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to uninstall ReSharper from VS2012 (or both if need be), reset the VS default settings, then resinstall ReSharper?

Answer (score 1):

It's a hard question, since ReSharper is storing its keyboard shortcuts and fonts/colors settings among VS ones, though all other settings are stored separately (ReSharper | Manage Options...)
You may back up all R# settings in 'Manage options...' dialog. However, if you are going to import/export VS keyboard and fonts settings, VS won't allow you to select only resharper- prefixed options.

Hope this info helps, however I'm not sure if it suitable for you or not...

Thanks.

Alex Berezoutsky,
Senior Support Engineer,
JetBrains, Inc.
"Develop with pleasure!"